# Execute a method when a view inside an activity is visible to the user?

Tags: android

I have a list of thumbnails , when a user scrolls over to a thumbnail, I want to perform some actions corresponding to that thumbnail. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the last visible and first visible positions in the list view and perform actions accordingly.
Suppose your listView is `listView`.

You can do this

`listView.getLastVisiblePosition()` to get the last visible position and 
 `listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` to get the first visible position.